# Express.js - How to pass socket to child_process

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

According to this

https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_example_sending_a_socket_object

you can easily pass a socket connection to a child process so that it can handle the socket transactions independently.  How do you achieve the same thing with the req.socket object provided in express where the client is making a socket request with io.socket.js? You cannot just do:

```
child.send("socket",req.socket")
```

because req.socket is not an instance of net.Socket so it fails the following checks

```
if (handle instanceof net.Socket) {
  message.type = 'net.Socket';
} else if (handle instanceof net.Server) {
  message.type = 'net.Server';
} else if (handle instanceof process.binding('tcp_wrap').TCP ||
       handle instanceof process.binding('pipe_wrap').Pipe) {
  message.type = 'net.Native';
} else if (handle instanceof dgram.Socket) {
  message.type = 'dgram.Socket';
} else if (handle instanceof process.binding('udp_wrap').UDP) {
  message.type = 'dgram.Native';
} else {
  throw new TypeError("This handle type can't be sent");
}
```

req.Socket appears only to be an instance of net.Socket when the request is a normal HTTP request (as opposed to having been initiated on the client with io.socket.js).

Comment: `req.socket instanceof net.Socket` evaluates to `true` for me (`express@4.14.0`, `node@6.9.1`, but also tested with Node v4 and v7).

Comment: Mmm, doesn't for me.  I am actually using sails.js something is different somewhere.  I will dig some more.

Comment: With ordinary HTTP requests req.socket appears to be an instance of net.Socket but any web socket requests from a client using io.socket.js are not. Not sure why this would but it seems that some augmentation is going on.

Comment: `socket.io` is a different thing, I doubt you'd be able to get it working in child processes, even _if_ you were able to pass the underlying socket to it. But wouldn't it be easier to use [`cluster`](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) to balance connections over multiple processes?

Comment: It seems so, which is a shame. Cluster in a bit OTT for what I need but I may have to look further into it.